# Significato e origine dell'espressione "all'ultima spiaggia"

Tags: idioms, etymology, meaning

In [questo articolo del Corriere della Sera](http://www.corriere.it/spettacoli/14_novembre_28/agon-channel-sogno-serie-b-chi-all-ultima-spiaggia-e70f184e-76c8-11e4-90d4-0eff89180b47.shtml) ho letto:

> "Il sogno di serie B per chi è all'ultima spiaggia."

Potreste spiegarmi qual è il significato dell'espressione "all'ultima spiaggia"? Sapreste dirmi qual è l'origine di questa espressione?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Essere all'ultima spiaggia" significa (in poche parole) "essere disperati".
Similmente, se qualcosa rappresenta "l'ultima spiaggia" significa che è l'ultima speranza, l'ultima possibilità.

La Treccani [lo spiega bene](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiaggia/) e dà anche una spiegazione dell'origine (che non conoscevo):

> Con uso fig., ultima s., ultima speranza, estrema possibilità di
>   risolvere una situazione: per molti lavoratori stranieri il nostro
>   paese è l’ultima s.; analogam.: essere, trovarsi all’ultima spiaggia.
>   Tale locuz. deriva dal titolo italiano, L’ultima spiaggia, del romanzo
>   On the beach (1957) dello scrittore ingl. N. Shute, e dell’omonimo
>   film statunitense (1959) del regista S. Kramer (film ambientato in
>   Australia, dove, dopo una guerra nucleare che ha annientato gli
>   abitanti di tutto il resto del mondo, la popolazione attende, con
>   l’arrivo della contaminazione atomica, la morte).

Comment: Veramente è curioso che l'origine sia il titolo di un romanzo.

Comment: Sì, effettivamente lo è. Di solito queste espressioni hanno origini più "popolari".

Comment: Grazie della segnalazione, karoshi. È veramente curioso: ci sono molte espressioni mutuate da titoli di libri o film (cronaca di un xxx annunciato, madre coraggio, a volte ritornano...), ma in genere rimangono confinate all'uso giornalistico, e talvolta usate a sproposito.

Comment: @DaG infatti gli esempi da te citati li ho visti usati solo da giornalisti e mi suonano pesanti e inflazionati. Sono anni che non li leggo in effetti ma li ho già sentiti. 

Invece *ultima spiaggia* è un'espressione usatissima nel linguaggio comune e non ne sapevo neanche l'origine. 
Secondo me il fatto che sia una figura di significato chiaro anche senza essere a conoscenza del riferimento culturale è determinante nella sua diffusione anche tra chi non ha mai sentito parlare del romanzo, al contrario delle altre che sono destinate all'oblio.

Comment: Lo si vede anche molto bene qui: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all%27ultima+spiaggia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%27ultima%20spiaggia%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Nemmeno io sapevo l'origine. Il film, comunque, è così impattante che non mi stupisce --- l'ho visto 30 anni fa, e qualche scena continua a girare nei miei incubi.

Answer (score -1):

Francesco Albergati Capacelli, 1785
Significato sembra molto vicino al simbolico nostro attuale... che ne dite?

[image]

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Personalmente non vedo in che senso il significato sia simbolico piuttosto che letterale (la spiaggia più a est del mediterraneo) in questo brano

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DenisNardin. Interessantissimo comunque il passaggio, sembrano quasi le parole di un dotto medievale! Posso chiederti quale sia la fonte?